# I am trying to show warning message when user click browser back button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I should display a warning message when the user clicks on browser back button. The message is **The browser back button should not be pressed** Using Javascript. I have tried so many types and searched so many queries, it is working when user click on browser back button alert box will display with default message, but I need to display **The browser back button should not be pressed** this message and two button **yes** and **no** button Please help me.

Comment: Y negative I did not under stand......

Comment: There's no question in "The browser back button should not be pressed" so exactly what should *yes* do and what should *no* do?   Use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: Ok sorry ....... Instead of yes or no button only one button i.e. OK .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per your requirement

```
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            var e = e || window.event;
             var msg = "The browser back button should not be pressed "

           // For IE and Fire[![enter image description here][1]][1]fox
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = msg;
        }

        // For Safari / chrome
        return msg;
     };
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2iyh.png]

Comment: same thing happening..... it is showing default message not my msg........

Comment: but exactly where..??

Comment: Yeah it is working... but my question is i need to display my message...... it is showing default message

Comment: is that possible..??

Comment: check my answer

Comment: "changes you made may not be saved".... I do not want display this message..... Instead that need to display this message "The browser back button should not be pressed"

Comment: It will help in chrome >34

Comment: what about chrome and fire fox ......  i still searching the answer......